# Background rise up within parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to rise up child div a bit to top.(without position attributes) The parent div has a background color. Please see the image.
[image]

I have tried with this code. But no luck.

```css
.parent {
  background: #3498db;
}

.child {
  background: #34495e;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Post a fiddle, it looks like your code should give you the desired outcome unless you've got other CSS code that is applying styles to these elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform`;

```
.child { transform: translateY(-100px); }
```

relative units are allowed too

Comment: You are a life savior! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this:

```css
.parent {
  background: #3498db;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  background: #34495e;
  margin: -60px auto 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```css
.parent {
  background: #3498db;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  margin:100px auto 0; 
}

.child {
  background: #34495e;  
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  top:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS property `transform` and check the working snippet below:

```css
body {
    transform: translateY(100px);
}

.parent{
    background: #3498db;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    height: 150px
}

.child{
    width: auto;
    height: 150px;
    background: #34495e;
    transform: translateY(-100px);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```